# Homebrew-compiled gpg-agent fails, gpg: cancelled by user

Tags: homebrew, gpg

I'm trying to get gpg-agent working on OS X, compiled with homebrew.

Here's my gpg-agent.conf:

```
djc@djc-mbp ~ $ cat .gnupg/gpg-agent.conf 
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-curses
no-grab
```

However, when I try to test it, it fails:

```
djc@djc-mbp ~ $ echo "test" | gpg -ase -r 30380381 | gpg

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Me <me@example.com>"
4096-bit RSA key, ID 30380381, created 2013-09-16

gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: no default secret key: bad passphrase
gpg: [stdin]: sign+encrypt failed: bad passphrase
gpg: processing message failed: eof
```

Any clues on how to get this working?